# Only client administrators can grant access to this app

Tags: sharepoint-server, app

I am trying to deploy an app via visual studio on my dev environment, however I am getting the following error:

> Sorry ... Only client administrators can grant access to this app.
>
> Allow it to fully control this collection of sites.
>
> Allow it to fully control this site.
>
> Allow access to the basic information of users of this site.
>
> Allow this application to run search queries on your behalf, ignoring the application's permissions on the result items.
>       Allow the application to access user profiles: Full Control
>
> Allow this application to access or edit Enterprise Managed Metadata Service.
>       Allow it to share permissions with other users.

In the appManifest I have given the following permissions:

```
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/taxonomy" Right="Write" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/search" Right="QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal" />
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You request `FullControl` on the social feature, in order to approve your app permission request, you approver should be tenant admin.
Most likely your user doesn't have sufficient permissions (ie. tenant admin) to approve the app.

Comment: This is a development environment. A few days ago it worked just fine. Now it does not.